# Reversing a Linked List (Help)

Tags: linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

So ListNodes have really been confusing me and I've been trying to understand snippets of code to see how they work, but the following reverse function I just can not understand especially the while loop can someone please explain it to me.

```
// Definition for singly-linked list:
// class ListNode<T> {
//   ListNode(T x) {
//     value = x;
//   }
//   T value;
//   ListNode<T> next;
// }
//

ListNode<Integer> reverse(ListNode<Integer> l) {
    if(l==null||l.next==null)
        return l;

    ListNode<Integer> p1 = l;
    ListNode<Integer> p2 = p1.next;

    l.next = null;

    while(p1!=null&& p2!=null){
        ListNode<Integer> t = p2.next;
        p2.next = p1;
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = t;
    }

    return p1;

}
```

Comment: what language i this?

Comment: @OmegaNalphA it's java

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, they make a temporary variable t that holds the extra value p2 is pointing to, switch the pointers between p1 and p2, then make the new p2 point to that temp variable. Since they already declared p2.next points to p1, its never removed even though p2 replaces it in the next line.

Its written kinda strangely though, usually I've seen it where the pointers are shuffled around rather than the way it is shown here.

Comment: What I don't understand is how the temporary variable t is able to hold on to the initial value of p2.next. For example, when ListNode<Integer> p1 = l and then we make l.next = null, this also causes p1.next = null. So therefore, if we're changing p2.next = p1, wouldn't this mean ListNode<Integer> t = p1 also?

Comment: I'm pretty sure in this case it is copying the value as in java they don't really deal with pointers so it is a copy of the object located in p2.next. One thing you can do to check is print the value of t and p2.next each time the execution happens (say, insert a string into each node that increments) and see what happens/how it changes